# How to fix an error in a php that uses mbstring?

Tags: php, linux, debian, mbstring

I am reviewing a web page running multiple php on a machine with Linux Debian.

Specifically, one of the php contains this code:

```
$methods = get_class_methods ( $class );
// Makes the content of $methods to be:
// $methods = ["__construct", "getId", "setId", "getVal", "setVal"]

$plength = count($methods);

for($i=0;$i<$plength;$i++) {
  if(stripos($methods[$i], "get")!==FALSE){
    $property = mb_substr($methods[$i], 3, mb_strlen($methods[$i], 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8');
    $setter = 'set'.mb_substr($methods[$i], 3, mb_strlen($methods[$i], 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8');

    // ...  
  }
}
```

When executing this php in the web browser, the error is displayed:

**Error
Call to undefined function mb_substr()**

indicating that the line that produces the error is the one that begins with

**$property =**

I have searched for information in various forums about this error and I have seen that it is due to the fact that mbstring is an extension that is not installed by default.

Running the command

```
php -m | grep mbstring
```

I check that mbstring is not installed, so it is necessary to install it.

So I have checked what version of php I have:

```
php -v
```

It shows that the installed version of php is **7.4.28**

And then I install mbstring with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php7.4-mbstring
```

Now the command

```
php -m | grep mbstring
```

shows
**mbstring**

However, the web browser still shows the same error than before:

**Error
Call to undefined function mb_substr()**

indicating that the line that produces the error is the one that begins with

**$property =**

I do not understand why it keeps showing this error if now mbstring is installed.

Would it be possible to modify the source code of the php so that it uses native php functions that don't require install anything extra (that doesn't use mbstring) ?

Comment: You may need to reboot your webserver. You can double-check the web installation by creating a file with `<?php phpinfo();`, then browse to that and see if mbstring is installed there

Comment: You don't need to _reboot_ the server, you just need to restart whichever _service_ is running the PHP processes, eg: apache, FPM, etc.